# onSubmit event nothing happens

Tags: javascript, css, xhtml

Here is my code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <head>
        <script type = "text/javascript">
          function validate(){
              var warnings = "some warnings";               
              document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML = warnings;
              document.getElementById("alert").styledisplay = "block";
              return true;
          }
        </script>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id = "alert"></div>
        <div id = wrapper>
          <h2>Enter Your Info</h2>
          <form name = "myForm" onSubmit = "javascript:validate()">
        <div>
          <label for = "username">User Name:</label>
          <input type = "text" name = "username" id = "username"/>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label for = "firstname">First Name:</label>
          <input type = "text" name = "firstname" id = "firstname"/>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label for = "lastname">Last Name:</label>
          <input type = "text" name = "lastname" id = "lastname"/>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label for = "password">Password:</label>
          <input type = "password" name = "password" id = "password"/>
         </div>
        <div>
          <input type = "submit" value = "submit" id = "submit"/>
        </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

The problem im having is when I click the submit button nothing happens. Not sure why, i am pretty new to java script and html but everything ive read said this should work any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: the alert div is currently styled with display : none;

Comment: Try removing the `javascript:` before validate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are always returning `true`. So the form will submit. Instead try this:

```
<form name="myForm" onSubmit="return validate()">
```

And

```
 function validate() {

     var warnings  = validate();

     document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML = warnings;
     document.getElementById("alert").styledisplay = "block";
     if(warnings) return false; //If any warning i don't want to submit.
     return true;
 }
```

just to add on. `if(warnings)` will fail the condition based on the initial state of warning you set or set nothing to it from your validate function (in case of validation success) return empty string  or return null, undefined etc or just return nothing...